# How to make breakpart two (black and blue) same height?

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, paracol

```
 %==================================================================
%Compilation --------------------------------------> txs:///xelatex
%==================================================================
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs, bookmark, blindtext}
\usepackage{calculator, color, calc, environ, fancyhdr, float, fontawesome, frcursive, comicneue, colortbl}
\usepackage{incgraph, ifthen, ifpdf}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum, lmodern, longtable, ltablex, mathrsfs, mdframed, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{paracol, pgf, pgffor, polyglossia, pspicture}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pstricks, pythontex}
\usepackage{scrextend, shapepar, siunitx, spreadtab, supertabular}
\usepackage{tabu, tabularcalc, tabularx, tcolorbox, tikz, tikzpagenodes,array}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc, tocloft, tocvsec2, type1cm}
\usepackage{varwidth, xcolor, xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}
%==================================================================
%==================================================================
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, external, fitting,
    hooks, , magazine, most, poster, 
    raster, skins, theorems, vignette, 
    %xprase, documentation, 
    %listings, minted
}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\newtcolorbox[]{boxe}[1][]{enhanced, 
    breakable, 
    #1}

%\NewTColorBox[init options]{envname}{specification}{options}


\begin{document}


\newtcolorbox[]{mybox}[1][]{enhanced jigsaw, breakable,
    equal height group=mybox, colframe=red, 
    watermark color=yellow!25!white,
    watermark text=\arabic{tcbbreakpart},
}



\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{mybox}
        \blindtext[5]
    \end{mybox}
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{mybox}
        \blindtext[6]
    \end{mybox}
\end{paracol}

%==================================================================
%==================================================================
\newpage
%==================================================================
%==================================================================

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please explain your question a bit more. What do you want to achieve? `How to make groups equal height after break …?` is not self-explaining.

Comment: look at the picture...

Comment: How to make two boxes same height....

Comment: Please, help me with the problem....

Comment: A manual solution `\begin{mybox}  \blindtext[5] \vspace*{6.3cm} \end{mybox}`

Comment: Is there an automatic command ?

Comment: For breakable boxes I do not think there is